# API to draw menu over leanback launcher?

Tags: android, android-tv

I'd like to create an app (actually just a menu) that should work just like the Android TV settings menu.

To be more specific, I'd like my app to cover only part of the screen and let any background video play on the remaining area (exactly like what happens with the settings menu).

Here's a picture of what I'd like to obtain:

[image: Android TV settings menu]

This means that I should be able to:

1. open Live Channels
2. play some content
3. press the home button (at this point the channel will be playing in background behind the leanback launcher)
4. open my app, and have the background content continue playing

Of this, I just need to figure out how to obtain point 4, the rest is just how Android TV works by default.

Just to be clear, I don't want advices on how to create an app that plays a video and has a side menu, I want to integrate this menu inside the existing Android TV background videos feature.

Is it possible? I can't find any API for this.

Comment: Hi. Did you do it ?
I also want display right menu (like a leanback setting menu) as picture above.

Comment: Nope, still looking for a solution

Answer (score 0):

For the app, you can do that using a transparent theme on the activity, that should keep the background visible (you can also decide to have a pseudo-transparent background to partially hide what's behind the activity, same way settings do).

The other question about playing the live channel on the background of the leanback launcher, I am not sure, but it sounds like it should be the standard procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what do you mean with "standard procedure"?

Comment: I mean that I don't think that part (playing media) is any different from whatever you are using to play media in the general case.

Comment: But I will not have any control over what the system is already playing before the user opens my app. As said, I just want the background video to continue playing while my app is open, like the settings app does.